# Most embedded list in a Clojure form

Tags: clojure

I am rather new to Clojure and I need to write a function which, given some Clojure form, replaces the most nested list with some value. For example:

```
(my-fn '(+ [* a b] (* c d) (* e (/ f g))) 'foo)
=> (+ (* a b) (* c d) (* e foo)) 
(my-fn '(+ [* a b] (* c d) (* e foo)) 'bar)
=> (+ [* a b] bar (* e foo))
```

I'm not asking for a full implementation but if somebody could give me a few pointers I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: is your second example correct?

Comment: Well, either (* c d) or (* e foo) is the most nested list in this case. I perhaps should have specified that only one list should be replaced at a time, so when there are multiple lists of the same depth then any one of them may be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a way to perform this operation in one pass in clojure's core library:
[zippers](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip)

the key is that you can traverse and modify the tree in context. It could look like this:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn replace-deepest [data replacer]
  (->> data
       z/seq-zip
       (iterate z/next)
       (take-while (complement z/end?))
       (apply max-key #(if (seq? (z/node %))
                         (count (z/path %))
                         -1))
       (#(z/replace % replacer))
       z/root))

user> (replace-deepest '(+ [* a b] (* c d) (* e (/ f g))) :asd)
;;=> (+ [* a b] (* c d) (* e :asd))

user> (replace-deepest '(+ [* a b] (* c (+ x (* y z)) d) (* e (/ f g))) :asd)
;;=> (+ [* a b] (* c (+ x :asd) d) (* e (/ f g)))
```

this approach traverses the collection depth-first collecting data, and then compares the `z/path` values count (the path is the part of aforementioned context). Then you can replace the node (in fact rebuild the tree with replaced value)

Answer (score 0):

As far as knowing what the 'greatest depth' is, you would need to first of all parse through all the forms just to find this answer, then do a second parse already knowing this. You might want a recursive function for each parse (so two recursive functions).

You could `map/mapv` (depending on whether the input is a `vector` or a `list`) over all the forms, recursing for any that satisfy `coll?`, otherwise keeping the form as it is if it is not 'some value', or changing it if it is, and is at the 'most deep' level.

You would also need to keep in the 'state' whether replacement has already been done at the deepest level, so that repeat replacements do not happen. State can be kept as parameters to the *second parse* recursive function. You might want an initial function that calls the recursive functions for the first time.

Note that `coll?` returns true for a map data structure, so you might want to use something more granular, such as `(some-fn list? vector?)` or `(every-pred coll? (complement map?))`. `seq?` won't work for vectors.

That was a *few pointers* and not a *full implementation*, suitable for a relative newcomer to Clojure. You will get a lot more out of doing it yourself based on some hints rather than following a zipper based solution.